# backbone.js не срабатывают события вида

Tags: backbone.js, события

Доброго времени суток. Пытаюсь разобраться с backbone.js. Есть пример http://megakolyan.ru/backbone/first/  хочу чтобы при клике по элементу .edit сработало событие editTask , но оно почему то не срабатывает.

Answer (score 0):

Негоже вот такую магию делать

```
this.$el = $('#todo');
```

Исправил ваш код. Обработчик метода click уже добавите сами.

```js
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
 
  defaults: {
 name: 'Dima',
 age: 23,
 occupation: 'web developer'
  }
  
});

var PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({
  
  tagName: 'li',
  template:_.template($('#person-id').html()),
  
  events: {
    'click': 'onClick'
  },
  
  initialize:function(){
    this.render();
  },
 
  render:function(){
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    
    $('#todo').html(this.$el);
    
    return this;
  },
  
  onClick: function(e) {
    if (e && e.preventDefault) {
      e.preventDefault();

      console.log('click');
    }
  }

});

var person = new Person();

var personView = new PersonView({ model: person });
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое - я не могу понять почему сейчас все работает, после того как я переписал код - this.$el = $('#todo');